# Using Tweepy in python and its following a given user but not exiting the loop

Tags: python, tweepy

Takes a given tweet id and will try to follow the user of that tweet.
When I check twitter I can see it has successfully followed the user but my while loop never exits.(This is all in the console)

```
def followUser(tweet):#Follows a user
    tweet = api.get_status(tweet.id)
    while tweet.user.follow_request_sent == False:
        api.create_friendship(tweet.user.id)
        followUser(tweet)
    print("Successful follow")
```

This is the error message when i ctrl-c

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in followUser
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 190, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 369, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 617, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 846, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

Comment: you never gave it a break!

Comment: Ok that makes sense that im not exiting the loop but im a bit of a noob and not sure where I would put that break statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this.

The `follow_request_sent` attribute of the [User object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) is undocumented as far as I can tell, but it seems to only be `True` when you've sent a follow request to a protected account and the user in question hasn't accepted it yet, so even if you're already following the user, this will be `False` and it won't be `True` at any point for an account that's not protected. This is what's causing the infinite loop.
Instead, you should use the `following` attribute as you did in your answer. However, note that this attribute is deprecated, so it might be prudent to use [`API.show_friendship`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.show_friendship) instead.
`not` should also be used in place of `== False` if you're not expecting any other falsey values, which I don't think `follow_request_sent` returns and which `following` definitely does not return.
Note, `following` is nullable, meaning Twitter's API can return "null", but [Tweepy converts it to `False`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/3df387deb4af34ef92c13a48cf19be957f4e2464/tweepy/models.py#L145-L150).

You're also recursively calling the function.
This, along with the loop, is completely unnecessary and very bad practice.

Since you already have the User object, you should just use its `follow` helper function instead of using `API.create_friendship`. This also sets the `following` attribute to `True`, so the User object will stay updated.

I'm not sure what the purpose of `tweet = api.get_status(tweet.id)` is if `tweet` is already a Status object. You're performing an unnecessary API request to get the same Status object you already have. You shouldn't need to refresh the Status object like this.

In your answer, you also have `id = tweet.retweeted_status.user.id`. Note that this will error if the status in question isn't a Retweet. You're also following the author of the original Tweet instead of the Retweet and performing another unnecessary API request to get the same User object you already have.

Note, [@Moshe Slavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8179099/moshe-slavin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463802/using-tweepy-in-python-and-its-following-a-given-user-but-not-exiting-the-loop/54465161#54465161) will infinitely loop because `counter` is not decremented and is always 100, and both @Moshe Slavi's answer and [@user15051990](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3623402/user15051990)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463802/using-tweepy-in-python-and-its-following-a-given-user-but-not-exiting-the-loop/54464088#54464088) will infinitely recurse if the user you're attempting to follow doesn't have a protected account.

For more information, see [my response on GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1166#issuecomment-459547535).

Answer (score 1):

As [@Haroldo_OK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679240/haroldo-ok) suggested use an `if` I added a counter:

```
def followUser(tweet): # Follows a user
    counter = 100
    while counter >= 0:
        tweet = api.get_status(tweet.id)
        # as [@harmon758][2] pointed out I forgot to subtract from the counter...
        counter -= 1
        if tweet.user.follow_request_sent == False:
            api.create_friendship(tweet.user.id)
            followUser(tweet)
            print("Successful follow")
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This isnt working either. Im wondering if this has something to do with how the tweepy module is performing the query rather than the code block. I think I will try raising an issue on github and see what the devs find.

Comment: @SegFault sound like a good idea! let us know what happens with the issue in github...

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I split out the refresh portion since im am calling that in other parts of the program as well.

```
def followUser(tweet):#Follows a user given a tweet id input
    id = tweet.retweeted_status.user.id
    if api.get_user(id).following == False:
        try:
            api.create_friendship(id)
            return followUser(refresh(tweet))
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            pass

def refresh(tweet):
    return api.get_status(tweet.id)
```

Comment: Good to have the correct answer for the question... :) Now if someone else has this problem they will have the answer! You should add some explaining to the answer too if you don't mind... Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
def followUser(tweet):#Follows a user
    tweet = api.get_status(tweet.id)
    while tweet.user.follow_request_sent == False:
        api.create_friendship(tweet.user.id)
        followUser(tweet)
        break
    print("Successful follow")
```

Comment: This will only try once, regardless of success; you could just as well use an `if`

Comment: I just tried that as well as a return followUser(tweet) and I am still not exiting. Edit:Added the debug output when exiting the command as well.

Comment: I was using the wrong api call to check for the follow status. Once I consulted the raw json I was able to find the correct query and that appears to be working.

Comment: @SegFault you should shear with us the query you used... For future user's with the same problem... You can add it as your own answer...

Comment: Oh didnt realize that, I edited one of the other replies but it needs a peer review. Also looks like my new account is time locked from marking my post as the answer.